# Do You know, how to use ADD command into memcached?

Tags: php, memcached, protocols

I'm using in my project many counters by memcached:

```
$data = $mc->set('sasa', 100);
$data = $mc->get('sasa');
var_dump($data);
$res =  $mc->add('sasa', 100);
var_dump($res);
```

result is

```
int(100)
bool(false)
int(100)
```

If I use memcached native protocol:

```
get sasa
VALUE sasa 1 3
100
END
add sasa 0 0 1
1
NOT_STORE
get sasa 
VALUE sasa 1 3
100
END
```

ADD command is not work. https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt#L132

Do You know, how to use ADD command in the memcached?

Comment: You are trying to `add` something that already exists? Memcached::add() is similar to Memcached::set(), but the operation fails if the key already exists on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you showed in your example is what should be expected. The ADD command will only add a key if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the usage of memory has reach the limit. Check it please, if yes, change the limit value in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to increment a counter. You can do this with the incr protocoll level or the Memcache::increment commands.

http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.increment.php